# Search for selected cell in a list and change cells value next to it

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing this problem, and i cant figure out if it can be done in VBA or not

i have a list of loans, each beneficiary stored in a row as following

```
loan# loan   jan2016 feb2016 mar2016 apr2016    
156   1000    -250    -250    -250    -250    
157   800     -200    -200    -200    -200    
158   1200    -300    -300    -300    -300
```

i receive a list contaning those who paid a payment
for example:

```
157 200    
158 300
```

so i what i do manually is to change the -200 to 200 for the loan 157 and -300 to 300 for 158 and so on

so what i thought about, is to:
select loan number, and click on a button, so the button event will search for the selected value in my loan list,find it and then change the next negative number to postive

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you any code yet ??

Comment: Yes it can be done in VBA
But so many questions; is the list a text file? what if the negative number and positive numbers are not the same? what if someone skips jan and then pays feb?

Comment: in addition to what @JReid said, what if someone pays a partial payment ... like 158 pays $150.

Comment: This would be rather simple to make and probably a little fun, but you'll need to provide a bit more information! If you want to try and put something together yourself, some methods to lookup would be `.Range().Offset()`, `.Range().Find()`, `InStr()` or `Replace()`, and `For Loops`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, lets make it more clear, yes it comes in a text file, but suppose i imported the text file to another worksheet, numbers will be always the same, because beneficiary is not allowed to pay different payment, beneficiary cannot also skip, and for the last question, no partial payment is allowed! Simply that

Comment: If there is no skipping, no partial, wouldn't all loans be on the list? Or do they have different dates i.e. Jan 07 you get list with loan 156 and Jan 21 you get list with loans 157 and 158???

Comment: @JReid all loans are on the list, and i have months from 2014 to 2017 which i fill the months for each loan

Comment: @ScottHoltzman answer should work with the fix I commented, however, if all the loans are on the list it sounds like you just want a Macro to convert all negative numbers to positive numbers for a given column, why bother opening the list of payments?

Comment: @JReid notice that not all loans are being paid on the same month, add for that i need to open the list  of payments because not all beneficiaries pay on the same day, i receive different beneficiary each day

Comment: Apologies I assumed when you responded all loans are on the list, the second question I asked was no. So this is a task you currently do manually but I'm guessing the number of times you do this is getting to be overwhelming, working with something like 50 columns and probably n-hundred rows. I can see the need for a macro. Let me think on it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the assumptions I made on sheet and range locations and adjust as needed. This is a great general shell, but there may be nuances in your data that you did not provide that may require code tweaks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyPayments()

Dim wsPay as Worksheet, wsLoans as Worksheet
Set wsPay = Worksheets("Payments")
Set wsLoans = Worksheets("Loans")

With wsPay

    Dim rPayment as range
    For each rPayment in .Range("A2:A100") 'assumes payments listed in this range
                                           'with loan number in col A and payment in B

        With wsLoans

            Dim rLoan as Range
            Set rLoan = .Columns(1).Find(rPayment.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
            'above assumes loans listed in column A of loan sheet.

            If Not rLoan is Nothing Then

                Dim rPayApply as Range
                Set rPayApply = rLoan.EntireRow.Find(rPayment.Offset(,1) * -1, lookat:=xlWhole)
                                                    'again, assumes payment amount in col B

                 If not rPayApply is Nothing Then rPayApply.Value = rPayApply.Value * -1

            End If

        End With

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Scott , but for some reason which i didn't figure out, it didn't work, i tried many times, with no change

Comment: @ScottHoltzman e.g. rPayment = 156 (loan number) now rLoan -> Row 2 of 'Loans' don't we need to update rPayment to be the amount paid?

Comment: @ygz82 - see now. I made an edit. I forgot to search on the inverse payment amount *(and was search for the loan number in the payment amount columns). Notice the Offset(,1) I added to 2nd find statement.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman unfortunately still not working, can you give it a try?

Comment: @ygz82 - it works perfectly for me given your sample data and the ranges I assigned it to in my code. Did you factor the range assumptions I made and adjust them for your data? Also, did you step through the code line-by-line to see where it's not behaving as you expect? Otherwise, it's hard for me to help without more details.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i tried and i moved to a new workbook ,i tested it several times line by line, with no result, so please have a look to the test worbook i made https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7twGUaOWATdb0o1enowa050MGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ygz82 - the code is not working for you because the payment amount of $335 for the loan 2978 is different than the schedule on the 'loan' tab ($300 a month). In your comments above you wrote *"numbers will be always the same, because beneficiary is not allowed to pay different payment"* - this is not the case in your test case.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks alot, it worked, i will put it under testing , hopefully i will not face any bugs, thanks again